# How to check if thread holds the monitor in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, multithreading, intellij-idea, ide, intellij-plugin

While working on `IntelliJ` , I am unable to check that if the thread is holding the lock or not.

On eclipse GUI there is a `lock` like icon against the thread , telling us that it is holding that `lock`.

In below code snapshot, my thread is at `notifyElementAdded()` and holding the lock however, in a thread stack there is no such Icon or intimation from `Intellij`

So my question is how to check the same on IntelliJ GUI.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps worth requesting a new feature from Jetbrains https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?q=thread%20holding%20lock

Answer (score 4):

There is actually a boolean attribute to the `Thread` class in Java - `Thread.holdsLock()`. 
To get the name of the thread which holds the monitor you can use the code example below:

```
public static long getMonitorOwner(Object obj)
{
    if (Thread.holdsLock(obj)) 
    {
        return Thread.currentThread().getId();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a similar functionality. But you can still check by getting the dump

[image: Get Thread Dump]

You can click on `Get Thread Dump` in Debug window and then you can see the `locked` in the log to see that the thread is actually holding the lock

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom variable in the Intellij debugging console using the plus button as shown in the image below.

Now every time you run the code in the debug mode, this variable will be re-calculated at your all debug points.

I created a variable- `Thread.holdsLock(AwsS3ClientHelper.class)` since I was acquiring a lock on the class itself. You can write any variable of your choice there. In your particular case, it will be `Thread.holdsLock(observers)`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be a potential feature request for IntelliJ to include this to their GUI product.

Programmatically, to verify this you can use the java.lang.Thread.holdsLock() method which returns true if and only if the current thread holds the monitor lock on the specified object

```
public static boolean holdsLock(Object obj)
```

Below snippet of run method for reference,

```
public void run() {

   /* returns true if thread holds monitor lock */

   // returns false
   System.out.println("Holds Lock = " + Thread.holdsLock(this));  

   synchronized (this) {
      // returns true
      System.out.println("Holds Lock = " + Thread.holdsLock(this));
   }
 }
```